# Estimating the tail of alternating harmonic sum

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am trying to solve a problem from an old qualification exam and want to prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} n \sum_{i=2n}^\infty \frac{(-1)^i}{i} = \frac{1}{4}.$$

I know that the limit exists because the sum is bounded by $\frac{1}{2n}$ in magnitude, so multiplying by $n$ and taking the limit gives $\frac{1}{2}$ as an upper bound. I was hoping to get some kind of integral approximation for the sum, but because of the alternating signs, I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: You can't, or else you wouldn't ask. Quite a few people here could, but you forgot to tell us why that would be interesting/important for anybody.

Comment: You are right, I can't. It's a problem from an old qualifying exam and I am trying to figure out how it's done to study.

Comment: It's an alternating series, with monotone decreasing terms. We know the tail is less than the first omitted term in absolute value, but when the terms decrease so slowly, it's close to one half of that (and that's what you have to prove).

Comment: It's okay to get stuck... what we do expect is that you provide motivation, and give us some indication you've seriously considered the question, any attempts (failed attempts are fine, just show your workings!)

Comment: Have you showed that the limit exists? If not, start there.

Comment: Nice job, @KrishnanMody, with the edit.  I have voted to reopen your question, given your improvements/edits!

Comment: Note that bounding the tail sum between $0$ and $\frac{1}{2n}$ doesn't guarantee that the limit exists. For an alternating series $\sum (-1)^n a_n$ ($(a_n)$ converges monotonically to $0$), the identity $$\sum_{n = k}^{\infty} (-1)^n a_n = \frac{(-1)^k}{2}a_k + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n = k}^{\infty} (-1)^n(a_n - a_{n+1})$$ can be quite useful to estimate the tail sums.

Comment: Thank you @DanielFischer. In my case, $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$, and I am starting the sum at $2k$ which means the first term on the right hand side of the identity gives $\frac{1}{4}$ after multiplying by $k$. The remainder is again an alternating sum, the first term of which has magnitude $\frac{1}{2k(2k+1)}$. So multiplying by $k$, the second term goes to $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an elementary approach:

$$\sum_{k=2n}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}k=\sum_{k=n}^\infty\left [\frac1{2k}-\frac1{2k+1}\right]$$

By the integral test,

$$\int_n^\infty\left[\frac1{2x}-\frac1{2x+1}\right]~\mathrm dx<\sum_{k=n}^\infty\left [\frac1{2k}-\frac1{2k+1}\right]<\int_{n-1}^\infty\left[\frac1{2x}-\frac1{2x+1}\right]~\mathrm dx$$

These limits may easily be evaluated using the squeeze theorem and L'Hospital's rule, noting that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\int_n^\infty f(x)~\mathrm dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\displaystyle\int_n^\infty f(x)~\mathrm dx}{1/n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{1/n^2}$$

Comment: Hmm you should put brackets; conventionally $\sum$ and $\prod$ have higher precedence than $+,-,\times,\div$.

Comment: Sounds good. Probably looks better too.

Comment: I recommend doing the same for the integrals too. A bit jarring to see the current version, though it's technically parseable...

Comment: Sure. I usually place parentheses or square brackets on my sums, though not often for integrals unless they get really messy.

Comment: There's actually a relevant mathematical reason; "dx" is like a little length that is multiplied by the integrand, in the sense that $(\frac1{2x}-\frac1{2x+1})\ dx = \frac{dx}{2x}-\frac{dx}{2x+1}$. So putting brackets makes more sense despite unambiguity in parsing. =)

Comment: =) are you a physicist who likes to multiply your differentials around?

Comment: No actually I don't, but it's commonly seen and intuitively interpreted that way, such as in physics where there is a meaningful distinction between multiplication by scalars and dot product with vectors. For example "$W = \int F·dx$" where $W$ is work done by force $F$ over path traced by $x$.

Answer (score 3):

$$n \sum_{i=2n}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^i}{i} = \frac{n}{2} \left(\Psi\left(n+\frac12\right) - \Psi(n)\right)$$ 
Now $$\eqalign{\Psi(n) &= \ln(n) - \frac{1}{2n} + O(1/n^2)\cr
\Psi\left(n+\frac12\right) &= \ln(n+1/2) - \frac{1}{2n+1} + O(1/n^2)\cr
&= \ln(n) + O(1/n^2)  }$$
so 
$$  \frac{n}{2} \left(\Psi\left(n+\frac12\right) - \Psi(n)\right) = \frac{1}{4} + O(1/n)$$

Answer (score 3):

You may like this method. By the Stolz theorem,
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{n\to\infty} n \sum_{i=2n}^\infty \frac{(-1)^i}{i} &=&
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{i=2n}^\infty \frac{(-1)^i}{i}}{\frac{1}{n}}\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{i=2(n+1)}^\infty \frac{(-1)^i}{i}-\sum_{i=2n}^\infty \frac{(-1)^i}{i}}{\frac1{n+1}-\frac1{n}}\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{-\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{2n+1}}{-\frac{1}{n(n+1)}}\\
&=& \frac{1}{4}
\end{eqnarray}